Насколько корректно выражение "балансируются мнения"?

Такой вопрос мне встретился в mail.ru и показался интересным. Почему? Никто из участников практически не дал ответа. Все как обычно: шутки, возмущения по поводу состояния современного языка и т. д.

Но вот я вижу термин: баланс мнений, и он мне кажется вполне адекватным. Можно ли исходя из этого понятия допустить применение выражения "балансируются мнения" в определенных ситуациях? Но есть еще сочетание два балансирующих мнения. Насколько оно корректно?


Примеры:
Там сталкиваются амбиция, там сталкиваются мнения, там балансируются мнения. Персонально ваш, September, 15, 2016
Это позволило бы создать площадку, где балансируются мнения всех людей, чтобы в диалоге рождалась истина, пишет Газета.Ru.


Балансируются мнения — корректное по смыслу выражение. Балансировать по словарю — это находиться в состоянии неустойчивости, раздвоенности. Б. между консерватизмом и радикализмом. Другими словами, искать приемлемый вариант между двумя точками зрения.

Мнения балансируются  означает мнения приводятся в равновесное состояние, отражающее разные точки зрения данной аудитории.
А как еще сказать — усредняются, уравновешиваются? Критикам слов  об этом надо задуматься. Но часто новые слова непонятны в том случае, если человек совсем не в теме.

Вот еще запись: Два балансирующих мнения не отменяют друг друга, а наоборот — вообще никогда не отменяют, в этом и смысл! это такой тест: если увидел в ком-то/где-то крайность, ищи тут же и другую, они будут вместе; если выбираешь между несовместимым — это тупик, а фишка значит в другом. Что ж, стоит задуматься)

Существует мини-техника: баланс мнений. Она определяет, на чьё мнение человек опирается при принятии решения — своё собственное или чужое.


Большой толковый словарь русского языка
БАЛАНСИРОВАТЬ, -рую, -руешь; нсв. 1. (чем). Сохранять 
равновесие при неустойчивом положении с помощью телодвижений 
или шеста. Б. руками, шестом. Б. на проволоке, трапеции. 2. 
(св. сбалансировать). что. Техн. Приводить в равновесие 
вращающиеся части машины (валы, шкивы, роторы и т.п.). 3. 
(св. сбалансировать). что. Достигать баланса (1.Б.; 2 зн.); 
уравновешивать. Б. бюджет. Б. спрос и предложение. 4. 
Находиться в состоянии неустойчивости, раздвоенности. Б. 
между консерватизмом и радикализмом. Б. на грани жизни и 
смерти. Балансирование, -я; ср. Балансировка, -и; ж. (2 
зн.). Б. колёс. Балансировочный, -ая, -ое. Б. груз. Б-ая 
машина.

